# how to sort multidimensional array

Tags: php

I have the following array:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [days] => Wed
        [count] => 0
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [days] => Tue
        [count] => 0
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [days] => Mon
        [count] => 1
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [days] => Sun
        [count] => 0
    )
```

And I want to sort it, so looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [3] => Array
        (
            [days] => Sun
            [count] => 0
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [days] => Mon
            [count] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [days] => Tue
            [count] => 0
        )

    [0] => Array
        (
            [days] => Wed
            [count] => 0
        )
```

Can any one help me to do this?

Comment: Define "like the following array". Reverse key order? Ascending order of `days` in subarray?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
usort($myArray, function($a, $b) {
    return $a['days'] - $b['days']; // your operation for checking value 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try a `usort`: If you are still on PHP 5.2 or earlier, you'll have to define a sorting function first:

```
function sortByOrder($a, $b) {
    return $a['days'] - $b['days'];
}

usort($myArray, 'sortByOrder');
```

Starting in PHP 5.3, you can use an anonymous function:

```
usort($myArray, function($a, $b) {
    return $a['days'] - $b['days'];
});
```

And finally with PHP 7 you can use the "spaceship operator":

```
usort($myArray, function($a, $b) {
    return $a['days'] <=> $b['days'];
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function compareOrder($a, $b)
    {
      return $a['days'] - $b['days'];
    }

    usort($array, 'compareOrder');
```

Answer (score 1):

The following php function could help:

```
bool array_multisort ( array &$array1 [, mixed $array1_sort_order = SORT_ASC [, mixed $array1_sort_flags = SORT_REGULAR [, mixed $... ]]] )
```

Answer (score 0):

May be this will help you

```
usort($inputArray, function($first, $second) {
    return $first['days'] - $second['days']; 
});
```